# React.js call components into setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a toaster component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/62n81oy4pr

in index.js, `this.setState({ toasterText: "Room added to summary." });`

from this code, you can change the value of the toaster whatever you want and When you click the button several times, the toaster keeps showing and then disappear after 2.6 sec from the last click.
However, When I set a component (or even a div) into the 'toasterText' and click the button,

something like this,
`this.setState({ toasterText: <Component>asdfasdf</Component> });`

the toaster appear by one click and disappear as soon as I click the button again.

I think I can do something with the componentDidUpdate or am I just not allowed to set components in setState??

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it "disappears" is because the component is re-mounted (destroyed and re-created), as opposed to re-rendered (text updated) in your first example.

While it is technically possible to do this, it is considered anti-pattern for numerous reasons (the problem you experienced being one of them). I can't think of any reason you'd ever want to take that approach; just stick with updating the text.

If you **really** have to implement the second approach, try adding a `key` prop to the component. That should prevent the re-mounting behavior.

Comment: Yup, I agree, no reason to do this.

Comment: I am so happy that I know the exact reason. the reason why I want to call components is There are several types of toasters in my site. like same feature but different styles.

Comment: @MijeongWon, then try saving the "type" of toast in your state also.